# Basic C Programming : Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'pro1' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c, initialization

I am a newbie to Computer Science and I'm currently studying first year in university.
I have a problem when comes to one question today.
The question is this :

> Write a program to allow the user to enter code and quantity sold for 3 products (use different variables to store these 5 different product codes). Your program is required to calculate the total amount for each product (quantity x unit price) and the grand total of all products sold.
>
> At the end, your program will display product code, product description, unit price and total amount for each product and also the grand total amount for all the products sold. Use the information on the following table as reference:
>
> [image: Table Reference]
>
> PS: you will be expected to have many variables used and many redundant of same codes appear in your program which is fine, because no looping is needed to apply here.
>
> Extra requirements :
>
> 1. Set the price to 2 decimal points
> 2. Fix the product code using constant method.
> 3. Use switch statement to get for the product price.
> 4. Include 6% tax calculation in the grand total.

Here is my answer, it is run with no error when I compile the code, but when I try to run it, it has the problem stated :

> *Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'pro1' is being used without being initialized.*

My answer code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float pro1, pro2, pro3, pro4, pro5;
float subtotal, Tax, total;
int unit;
char code;
int x, y, z, a, b;

printf("Enter the quantity of the product.\n");
scanf("%d", &unit);
printf("Enter the product code.(x=12345,y=56789,z=45678,a=13579,b=34567)\n");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch (code)
{
case 'x':
    pro1 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'y':
    pro2 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'z':
    pro3 = unit*1.20;
    break;
case 'a':
    pro4 = unit*4.50;
    break;
case 'b':
    pro5 = unit*1.00;
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Enter the quantity of the product.\n");
scanf("%d", &unit);
printf("Enter the product code.(x=12345,y=56789,z=45678,a=13579,b=34567)\n");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch (code)
{
case 'x':
    pro1 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'y':
    pro2 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'z':
    pro3 = unit*1.20;
    break;
case 'a':
    pro4 = unit*4.50;
    break;
case 'b':
    pro5 = unit*1.00;
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Enter the quantity of the product.\n");
scanf("%d", &unit);
printf("Enter the product code.(x=12345,y=56789,z=45678,a=13579,b=34567)\n");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch (code)
{
case 'x':
    pro1 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'y':
    pro2 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'z':
    pro3 = unit*1.20;
    break;
case 'a':
    pro4 = unit*4.50;
    break;
case 'b':
    pro5 = unit*1.00;
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Enter the quantity of the product.\n");
scanf("%d", &unit);
printf("Enter the product code.(x=12345,y=56789,z=45678,a=13579,b=34567)\n");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch (code)
{
case 'x':
    pro1 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'y':
    pro2 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'z':
    pro3 = unit*1.20;
    break;
case 'a':
    pro4 = unit*4.50;
    break;
case 'b':
    pro5 = unit*1.00;
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Enter the quantity of the product.\n");
scanf("%d", &unit);
printf("Enter the product code.(x=12345,y=56789,z=45678,a=13579,b=34567)\n");
scanf("%d", &code);

switch (code)
{
case 'x':
    pro1 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'y':
    pro2 = unit*3.50;
    break;
case 'z':
    pro3 = unit*1.20;
    break;
case 'a':
    pro4 = unit*4.50;
    break;
case 'b':
    pro5 = unit*1.00;
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Artline 500A Black (Whiteboard Marker): %f", pro1);
printf("Artline 500A Red (Whiteboard Marker): %f", pro2);
printf("Pocket File (Yellow): %f", pro3);
printf("Pencil Casing: RM %f", pro4);
printf("A4 Exercise Book: %f", pro5);

subtotal = pro1 + pro2 + pro3 + pro4 + pro5;
Tax = subtotal*0.06;
total = subtotal + Tax;

printf("Subtotal : %f", subtotal);
printf("Tax : %f", Tax);
printf("Total : %f", total);

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

I have only learned so far about basic I/O operations, if-else statements and switch case statements.

Comment: You can't use a `for` loop yet? I think if you know `switch` you should know `for` or `while`.

Comment: You haven't set any of your `pro` variables to an initial value. What happens if the user never selects the code for one of these variables? It won't have a value...

Comment: We are not allow to use loop in this question ...

Comment: Thanks , Evert. I know it now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your code:

1. You are violating the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in a way that is actually exagerated.
2. You never check the return value from `scanf()` that could lead to the variable keeping it's previous value or being uninitialized when you use it.
3. You print the value of the `probN` variables but it might happen that the user never inputs the code for the `N`th product.

   You should initialize them to `0`, because if the value was never inserted by the user it means that "*no units*" were sold.
4. Your `switch` statement **will never work**, if you input `x` with the `"%d"` specifier the second point of these 4 points will be a problem because `code` will be uninitialized when you reach the `switch`, you should use the `"%c"` specifier instead and check the value returned by `scanf()` to be sure that something was scanned.

   So instead of

   ```
   scanf("%d", &code);
   ```

   you need

   ```
   if (scanf(" %c", &code) != 1)
       wow_this_is_really_unexpected_but_I_am_glad_to_be_careful();
   ```

   it's also wrong to pass a `char *` when using the `"%d"` specifier, and it's actually a serious bug.

Comment: Thank you ! I will be more careful from now on in initialize local variables and test the return of scanf.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine all your `switch` statements go through the `default`case, and you hit the `printf()` with `pro`.

Certainly a read before write scenario for an uninitialized automatic local variable will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your application, as the value your're trying to read is indeterminate.

Suggestion: Always initialize your local variables.

Comment: Thanks, I know it now, must initialize the local variables. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What value has `pro1` if the user never gave `x` as the code? Then `pro1` is never assigned a value--which in C lingo means it is *uninitialized* when the control reaches

```
subtotal = pro1 + pro2 + pro3 + pro4 + pro5;
```

If the intent is to use 0 for products that aren't used, you should initialize them with

```
float pro1 = 0, pro2 = 0, pro3 = 0, pro4 = 0, pro5 = 0;
```

**Important: there's another bug in**

```
char code;
scanf("%d", &code);
```

`code` must be an `int` if you scan with a `%d` format. Turn on all the warnings of your compiler! In addition, you *must* test the return of `scanf` with

```
if (scanf("%d", &code) != 1) {
    /* error: could not convert the input to a number. */
}
```

Not checking the return from `scanf` is a sure recipe for surprises.

Comment: Thank you for you to point out my bug. Thank you ! I will be more careful from now on in this kind of error and warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variables,

```
float pro1=0, pro2=0, pro3=0, pro4=0, pro5=0;
```

It can happen that these variables are used without any value set during the `switch` statements if it falls through `default` case.

Comment: Thank you, I know it now and will take note for it to make this won't happened in my future code anymore. Thanks !